# Turn off comments for given CPT checkbox?

Tags: custom-post-types, comments

I'm wondering what's the best way of turning off comments for a Custom Post Type?

I don't want to turn it off completely which is quite easy but to create a checkbox in wp-admin that will turn off comments if checked and show them as usual if not.

Any ideas? :)

Comment: What have you tried? What are your specific conditions? The obvious answer is the Options API, but where do want the controls (among other details)?

Comment: I'd love to use the Settings API, the easiest way that should definitely work is to create some setting and then in single-customposttypename.php do something like if(setting) // do comments. Although I'm wondering if there's any other, more elegant/proper way :)

Comment: Won't the built in wp option to disable comments on posts and pages be enough?
Or, are you trying to enable/disable for all posts at once?